# How do you find the union of the the unit squares contained in a polygon?

Tags: computational-geometry

**The Problem:**

Suppose you have a simple polygon (edges don't cross).  Find the union of of all 1x1 squares that fit in the polygon.  To be clear, I am asking for the union of all points that are in some square that fits into the polygon.  Maybe the border of this union can be expressed as a shape whose edges are line segments and arcs of circles.

**Motivation:**

I am working on a computer vision project where I find beds in birds-eye-views of rooms.  I have a filter which fairly effectively removes the floor and the wall from consideration.

I would like to apply a filter on the remaining data that throws out points that cannot be in a bed-sized rectangle contained in the stuff that's left from my first filter, but does not throw out the bed.  It leaves some extra stuff as well.

I have written an iterative approximate solution.  Specifically, it discretizes the set of angles it tries.  I imagine that an exact solution could be faster as well as more precise.

To make the problem more appealing and perhaps more doable, I have only asked for fitting unit squares in the polygon.  I would be happy to know the solution to the more general problem of an arbitrary fixed-size polygon.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Take a look at [morphological operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology).  Do any of them do what you are looking for?

Comment: @D.W. I think the morphological operator perspective helps, but I can't bring it all the way home.  Specifically, the set of points contained in a square OF A FIXED ORIENTATION in the polygon is the erosion using that square as the structuring element, followed by dilation with the same square.  What I'm after is the union of the result of the those morphological operations over all orientations of the square.